# Repository pattern with hierarchical datastructure

Tags: .net, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I have a hierarchical datastructure (it is stored in an xml file) and I want to encapsulate the data layer in some kind of interface to access the data from the bussiness layer.

It seems that repository pattern with unit of work could be a good way of encapsulating the datamodel, but I can't really see how to do it..:

My data is grouped as follows

- TestPlan

  - TestSequence list

    - TestMethod
    - GroupReference
    - TestMethod etc
  - GroupsOfTestmethods list

    - Group

      - List of testmethods

        - TestMethod
        - GroupReference
        - TestMethod
    - Group etc

I've tried several approached, but it seems that Repository/UoW patteen is good for mapping flat tables rather than a hierarchical structure.

For instance, making

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity); 
    T GetByName(string name);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

And then a

```
interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Group> GroupsOfTestmethods { get; }
    IRepository<groupitembase> TestSequence { get; } // groupitembase is base class for TestMethod and GroupReference
    void Save();
}
```

Now, if I want a TestMethod I have to traverse both the TestSequence list and all Groups in GroupsOfTestmethods to be sure to find it. However it would be nice to have a common function for getting a TestMethod item regardless in what list it is located in..

Any suggestions on how to construct a Repository/UoW implementation, or any data access layer to a hierarchical structure?

Regards Anders